# Check for Capitalization of second word in mysql field

Tags: mysql, capitalization

Sort of mysql newbie, in Excel I'd do something like 'IsProper' but all I am trying to find here is is the first letter of the second word in the string upper case or not? Or even are ALL words in the field Init Caps or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to grab all rows where the first letter of the second word is capital

```sql
SELECT t.*, SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(column1, ' ', 2), ' ', -1) second_word 
  FROM Table1 t
 WHERE CHAR_LENGTH(column1) - CHAR_LENGTH(REPLACE(column1, ' ', '')) > 1
HAVING BINARY LEFT(second_word, 1) = BINARY UPPER(LEFT(second_word, 1))
```

Given sample data like this

```
| ID |            COLUMN1 |
---------------------------
|  1 | first second third |
|  2 | first Second third |
|  3 |              first |
|  4 |               NULL |
```

The output from the query

```
| ID |            COLUMN1 | SECOND_WORD |
-----------------------------------------
|  2 | first Second third |      Second |
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f5d9b/5)** demo

Comment: Thanks, awesome, works like a charm.  Being the astoundingly intelligent guy I am I even figured out how to grab where second word is not caps by changing UPPER to LOWER ;). Sorry I coudn't vote you up I'm new but I did check as right/good answer. Thanks again.